# Find the coordinates of the points on $y=-(x+1)^2+4$ that have a distance of $\sqrt {14}$ to $(-1,2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Create a function that gives the distance between the point $(-1,2)$  the graph of $$y=-(x+1)^2+4.$$ Find the coordinates of the points on the curve that have a distance of $\sqrt {14}$ units from the point $(-1,2)$.

I know that the $x$-intercepts are $x=1$ and $x=-3$, and that the vertex is $(-1,4)$. I'm trying to use the distance formula by equating $\sqrt{14}$ to the function, but that is not getting me anywhere. 
$$
d(x) = \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + \big(-(x+1)^2 + 2\big)^2}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I think you have the right formula for the distance, just solve it for $x$ when $d^2=14$

Comment: When I did that I got x=-5 and x=2, which is not on the function y=-(x+1)^2+4  because the x-intercepts are x=-3 and x=1 :(

Comment: @Lauren If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

The locus of points whose distance from $(-1,2)$ is $\sqrt{14}$ is the circle

$(x+1)^2+(y-2)^2=14$

that is

$\color{red}{x^2+2 x}+y^2-4 y-9=0$

The parabola equation can be written as $\color{red}{x^2+2 x}=\color{blue}{3-y}\quad(*)$

Therefore the intersection points, the points of the parabola which are $\sqrt{14}$ from the given point, can be found solving

$\color{blue}{3-y} +y^2-4 y-9=0$

which gives $y_1=-1;\;y_2=6$

plugging  back $y_1$ in $(*)$

$x^2+2x=4$ gives $x=-1\pm\sqrt 5$

while the other gives no real solutions

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Raffaele. Very nice graphical representation.

Comment: @Raffaele If you subdtitute $y_1=-1$ into $(*)$ then you get the equation $x^2+2x=4$...

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve $$\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + \big(-(x+1)^2 + 2\big)^2}=\sqrt{14}.$$ Squaring both parts and substituting $u=(x+1)^2$ we get a quadratic equation $u^2-3u-10=0$ which has two roots, $u=5$ and $u=-2$. Only $(x+1)^2=5$ is possible for real numbers so we get $x=\sqrt5-1$ and $x=-\sqrt5-1$

Answer (score 0):

this function is given by $$d=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+((x+1)^2-2)^2}$$
simplifying the radicand we have $$d=\sqrt{3\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+2+{x}^{4}+4\,{x}^{3}}$$
defining $$d^2=3\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+2+{x}^{4}+4\,{x}^{3}$$ so we find the first derivative as $$6\,x-2+4\,{x}^{3}+12\,{x}^{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for the distance is correct. So if you want this distance to be equal to $\sqrt{14} $ then you need to solve 
$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + \big(-(x+1)^2 + 2\big)^2}=\sqrt{14}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x+1)^2=t$, where $t\geq0$.

Thus, we need to solve $t+(t-2)^2=14$.

I hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Consider : $y': = y - 2;$ $x':= x+1.$

Express the equations in terms of a translated coordinate system $Y'X'$, with its origin at $(-1,2)$. A translation does not alter  length, it suffices to find the distance of the parabola' (x',y') to (0,0).

$\star)$ $ y' = -(x')^2 + 2.$

(Distance)$^2$:

$(x')^2 + (y')^2 =$

$ - y' + 2 + (y')^2 = 14$.

$(y')^2 - y' -12 = 0.$

$(y' -4)(y' +3) = 0.$

$y'_1=4;$ $y'_2=-3.$

No solution for $y'_1= 4.$

$y'_2 = -3$ yields: $ x' = {^+_-}√5$.

And back to the original coordinates $x,y$:

$(√5-1,-1)$ and $(-√5 -1,-1)$.